# How to add text view just bellow the the lottianimation view?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the below XML code I want to add a text view of fetching data just center below of lottianimation view. please tell me how to do it because when I add text view below lottianimation view it places at the bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Navigation.mainActivityFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?colorPrimaryVariant">

        <com.example.scoopBook.HelperClass.VerticalViewPager
            android:id="@+id/verticalViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/loading"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/internetConnection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please connect to Internet\nand restart app "
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout`  `layout_below` attribute to add it below `LottieAnimationView`.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: I tried that attribute and it placed the text below the lotti animation view but the space between them is so much.

Comment: @sam this might be because the content you put in `LottieAnimationView` takes much space, you can try to change height & width of the `LottieAnimationView` to fixed dp values and see